# How to display error message based on custom validation rules in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I am using a template-driven approach to building forms in Angular 2 and I have successfully created custom validators that I can use in the template.

However, I can't find a way to display specific error message bound to specific errors. I want to differentiate why the form is not valid. How do I achive that?

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

    import { Site } from './../site';

    import { BackendService } from './../backend.service';

    import { email } from './../validators';

    import { CustomValidators } from './../validators';

    @Component({
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/form.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['app/css/form.css'],
        directives: [CustomValidators.Email, CustomValidators.Url, CustomValidators.Goof],
        providers: [BackendService]
    })

    export class FormComponent {
        active = true;
        submitted = false;
        model = new Site();

        onSubmit() {
            this.submitted = true;
            console.log(this.model);
        }

        resetForm() {
            this.model = new Site();
            this.submitted = false;
            this.active = false;
            setTimeout(() => this.active = true, 0);
        }

        get diagnostics() {
            return JSON.stringify(this.model)
        }
    }

import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BackendService } from './backend.service';

function validateEmailFactory(backend:BackendService) {
    return (c:FormControl) => {
        let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

        return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
            validateEmail: {
                valid: false
            }
        };
    };
}

export module CustomValidators {

    @Directive({
        selector: '[email][ngModel],[email][formControl]',
        providers: [
            {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomValidators.Email), multi: true}
        ]
    })
    export class Email {
        validator:Function;

        constructor(backend:BackendService) {
            this.validator = validateEmailFactory(backend);
        }

        validate(c:FormControl) {
            return this.validator(c);
        }
    }

    @Directive({
        selector: '[url][ngModel],[url][formControl]',
        providers: [
            {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomValidators.Url), multi: true}
        ]
    })
    export class Url {
        validator:Function;

        constructor(backend:BackendService) {
            this.validator = validateEmailFactory(backend);
        }

        validate(c:FormControl) {
            var pattern = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/;

            return pattern.test(c.value) ? null : {
                validateEmail: {
                    valid: false
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Directive({
        selector: '[goof][ngModel],[goof][formControl]',
        providers: [
            {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomValidators.Goof), multi: true}
        ]
    })
    export class Goof {
        validate(c:FormControl) {
            return {
                validateGoof: {
                    valid: false
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can just check the [`AbstractControl#hasError(...)`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#hasError-anchor) method to see if the control has a specific error. `FormGroup` and `FormControl` are both `AbstractControl`s. for `FormControl` you just pass as an argument the error name. For example

```
function regexValidator(control: FormControl): {[key:string]: boolean} {
  if (!control.value.match(/^pee/)) {
    return { 'badName': true };
  }
}

<div *ngIf="!nameCtrl.valid && nameCtrl.hasError('badName')"
     class="error">Name must start with <tt>pee</tt>.
</div>
```

The validator method should return a string/boolean map, where the key is the name of the error. This is the name that you check for in `hasError` method.

For `FormGroup` you can pass as an extra parameter the path to the `FormControl`.

```
<div *ngIf="!form.valid && form.hasError('required', ['name'])"
     class="error">Form name is required.</div>
```

`name` is simply the identifier of the `FormControl` for the input.

Here is an example with both the `FormControl` and the `FormGroup` check.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
  AbstractControl,
  REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES
} from '@angular/forms';

function regexValidator(control: FormControl): {[key:string]: boolean} {
  if (!control.value.match(/^pee/)) {
    return { 'badName': true };
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'validation-errors-demo',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Differentiate Validation Errors</h2>
      <h4>Type in "peeskillet"</h4>
      <form [formGroup]="form">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" [formControl]="nameCtrl"/>
        <div *ngIf="!nameCtrl.valid && nameCtrl.hasError('required')"
             class="error">Name is required.</div>
        <div *ngIf="!nameCtrl.valid && nameCtrl.hasError('badName')"
             class="error">Name must start with <tt>pee</tt>.</div>
        <div *ngIf="!form.valid && form.hasError('required', ['name'])"
             class="error">Form name is required.</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .error {
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #AB4F5B;
      color: #AB4F5B;
      background-color: #F7CBD1;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  `],
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [FormBuilder]
})
export class ValidationErrorsDemoComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  nameCtrl: AbstractControl;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    let name = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
      Validators.required, regexValidator
    ]));
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      name: name
    });
    this.nameCtrl = this.form.controls['name'];
  }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Ok so I got it working, but it's a little verbose. I couldn't figure out how to properly get access to the individual `FormControl` of the inputs. So what I did was just create a reference to the `FormGroup`

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
```

Then then to check for validity, I just use the `hasError` overload that passed the path of the form control name. For `<input>` that use `name` and `ngModel`, the `name` value gets added to the main `FormGroup` with that name as the `FormControl` name. So you can access it like

```
`f.form.hasError('require', ['nameCtrl'])`
```

assuming `name=nameCtrl`. Notice the `f.form`. The `f` is the `NgForm` instance which has a `FormGroup` member variable `form`.

Below is the refactored example

```
import { Component, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  Validators,
  AbstractControl,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES
} from '@angular/forms';

function validateRegex(control: FormControl): {[key:string]: boolean} {
  if (!control.value || !control.value.match(/^pee/)) {
    return { 'badName': true };
  }
}
@Directive({
  selector: '[validateRegex]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useValue: validateRegex, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class RegexValidator {
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'validation-errors-template-demo',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Differentiate Validation Errors</h2>
      <h4>Type in "peeskillet"</h4>
      <form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>

        <input type="text" name="nameCtrl" ngModel validateRegex required />

        <div *ngIf="!f.form.valid && f.form.hasError('badName', ['nameCtrl'])"
             class="error">Name must start with <tt>pee</tt>.</div>

        <div *ngIf="!f.form.valid && f.form.hasError('required', ['nameCtrl'])"
             class="error">Name is required.</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .error {
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #AB4F5B;
      color: #AB4F5B;
      background-color: #F7CBD1;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  `],
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, RegexValidator]
})
export class ValidationErrorsTemplateDemoComponent {

}
```

Comment: This is helpful, however you are using model-driven approach to building forms (using FormBuilder). When I use template-driven, I don't know how to expose the AbstractControl in html to ask it if it has error. I always get hasError is not a function or something similar.

Comment: In your template, these models are created implicitly to represent the inputs. You can still access them from the template without have any member model variables at all. You just need to create reference variables in your template. If you post a more complete example, I can try and help you with that

Comment: For instance, in your form you can do `<form #f="ngForm">`, and now `f` is the variable that represent the `FormGroup`. `ngForm` is something that is provided, so you don't need to worry about where that comes from. Also for your different inputs you can use `<input #nameInput [formControl]="nameInput">`, and the `nameInput` would be added to the `f` form as a `FormControl`. There are a lot of different ways to set up declarative templates. If you need to more help, I will probably need to see your setup in your template

Comment: I would like a simple form with 1 input (declaratively) that is two-way bound with model AND I have access to the AbstractControl form the template to check it's validity and custom errors. [formControl]="nameInput" throws Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known native property

Comment: Check out my update. I got it working, but not they way I thought it _should_ work. Seems my assumptions were incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote set of directives similar to `ng-messages` from AngularJs to tackle this problem in Angular. https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/ngx-messages

```
<div [val-messages]="myForm.get('email')">
  <span val-message="required">Please provide email address</span>
  <span val-message="server" useErrorValue="true"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For template driven validation, use an attribute directive as below:

```
import { Model } from '../../models';
import { Directive, Attribute, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[unique-in-list][formControlName],[unique-in-list][formControl],[unique-in-list][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => UniqueInListDirectiveValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class UniqueInListDirectiveValidator implements Validator {
     @Input('list') private list: Model[];
     @Input('property') private _property: string;
     @Input('thisid') private _myId: string;

     validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {

        let currValue = control.value;
        if (currValue && currValue.length > 0 && this.list && Array.isArray(this.list) && this.list.length > 0) {
            let model = this.list.find(
                (testModel: Model) => {
                    return testModel.modelId !== this._myId && testModel[this._property] === currValue;
                }
            );
            if (model) {
                return { isUnique: true }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

.. with the accompanying markup in your template:

```
<input
    type="text"
    #nameVar="ngModel"
    name="name"
    class="form-control name-field"
    unique-in-list
    [list]="models"
    [thisid]="model.modelId"
    property="name"
    [(ngModel)]="model.name"
    required
/>
<div *ngIf="nameVar.errors?.required && (submitted || !nameVar.pristine)" class="alert-classes-here">
    <div>Name is required</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="nameVar.errors?.isUnique && (submitted || !nameVar.pristine)" class="alert-classes-here">
    <div>Name is already taken</div>
</div>
```

HTH